# File Handling: Prompt user for info and save filename with this info

Tags: python, file-handling

Hi I would like to ask a user for certain information e.g Part number / Order number / Serial number / network file path and then use this information to create the actual file name for example:

```
Part number = 111234
Order number = WO98765
Serial Number = SN001
```

`Path = (browseable to correct folder on network)`
The file would then be saved as follows:

`111234_WO98765_SN001`.*** into the selected folder

If possible the next time the script was run then it would remember the last details entered, e.g if you were working on the same part number and order number then the user would only have to change to the appropiate serial number

Comment: Something like: `filename = '_'.join([str(part_number), str(order_number), str(serial_number)])`, `filepath = os.path.join(network_folder_path, filename)` would create the filename and determine the path to store it. To remember the last details you'll need to save them in a file and read it when the script starts (if it exists).

Comment: Fantastic Arman thanks a lot Ill try this now

Comment: I am not Arman, if you are referring to my comment...

Comment: Sorry my mistake, im on an old ie and the layout showed arman next to your comment

Answer (score 0):

You could use [picke](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html) to save this information. Or just in txt file.